# Only the left menu toolbar is showing up on Wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress

When I log in to my Wordpress admin, only the left menu toolbar is showing. Nothing else is displaying. The website front end works fine.

What I've done so far to investigate:

- Renamed plugins folder to pluginz to make sure none of the plugins are doing this
- Made sure there is no javascript error on the page
- Made sure there is no 404 errors
- Temporarily removed .htaccess to eliminate possible htaccess issues
- Made sure there is no fatal php error thrown on admin

Any idea what might be going on?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing the same for your theme folder? Failing that download the same version of WP and replace the core.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to fix the issue with help from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/127486) :

To fix the bug:

- Open file blog/wp-admin/includes/screen.php in your favorite text editor.
- On line 706 find the following PHP statement: `<?php echo self::$this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
  Replace it with the statement: `<?php echo $this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
- Save your changes.